# How can I cluster 3-dimensional data?

Tags: data-mining, data, clustering, fuzzy-classification

For a project in my data mining class, I am to perform fuzzy-c means clustering on a data set, where each data point has 3 axes.I'm not exactly sure how I would do so, especially given the clustering algorithm I'm using. Here's an example of the data set I'm using;

| - | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2 | 5 | 5 |
| banana | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| carrot | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| durian | 6 | 7 | 1 |
| eggplant | 0 | 3 | 6 |

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A [quick google search](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=fuzzy+c+means+github) gives relevant results, including [examples of how to do it](https://github.com/omadson/fuzzy-c-means). What have you tried up to now? What problems have you faced?

Comment: My professor wants us to implement the clustering ourselves. I was really struggling to grasp the concept of a 3-dimensional dataset and how you would cluster it as well as recalculating the centroids but after reviewing dozens of videos, I think I can do it. Thank you for taking the time to send the link!